# how to change gnome 3.2.6 panel background color

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

I am using **ubunut 12.10** with **gnome-shell 3.6.2** . I want to change the background color of the panel appearing top of the screen. 
I am currently using following theme as described in Tweak Tool:
Current Theme :Adwaita
Cursor Theme: Adwaita
Gtk+ Theme: Adwaita
I have tried using **gconf-editor** and **dconf-editor** but none of them are showing the background color option for the panel.
Can any one suggest me a solution to above ?

Comment: You have to edit the GTK Theme itself, and by the way Adwaita is compiled into a binary file so you'll have to use another theme to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnome-shell styles for the top panel are determined by the CSS file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`.

The top panel is styled by the `#panel` ID:

```
#panel {                     
    background-color: black;  /* <--- */
    font-weight: bold;       
    height: 1.86em;          
}
```

You can change that background colour to one you like.

You might also wish to change the `.panel-corner` class' `-panel-corner-background-color` colour to get those two rounded corners on the bottom-left and -right of the top panel to change colour:

```
.panel-corner {
    -panel-corner-radius: 6px;
    -panel-corner-background-color: black; /* <--- */
    -panel-corner-border-width: 2px;   
    -panel-corner-border-color: transparent;
}
```

If you wish to avoid modifying the *global* file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`, you could make your own theme for gnome-shell (these can be set with the `gnome-tweak-tool` program). I am fuzzier on the details here, but I suspect you can  copy the entire `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` folder (so that you have all the pictures the theme requires) and modify the CSS file, which will provide you with a complete theme.